# Increasing Rank based on year in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes for year 2022,year 2021 and year 2020 as given below:

```
ID  YEAR  RANK
500 2022   1
510 2022   2
520 2022   3
```

```
ID  YEAR  RANK
501 2021   1
550 2021   2
560 2021   3

ID  YEAR  RANK
505 2020   1
506 2020   2
507 2020   3
```

I have to append year 2020 dataframe below year 2021 dataframe and 2022 dataframe needs to be at top and reassign the rank as given in below output:

```
ID  YEAR  RANK
500 2022   1
510 2022   2
520 2022   3
501 2021   4
550 2021   5
560 2021   6
505 2020   7
506 2020   8
507 2020   9

In above output I need to reassign the rank in a way that rank for year 2022 dataframe needs to be same but for first Id of year 2021 rank needs to be 4 which 1 higher than highest rank for year 2022 and so on. Similarly for year 2020 if highest rank for year 2021 is 6 rank for first Id for year 2020 rank needs to be 7 and so on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add maximal rank to all ranks of `df1` first and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df2 = df2.assign(RANK = df2.RANK + df1.RANK.max())

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    ID  YEAR  RANK
0  500  2022     1
1  510  2022     2
2  520  2022     3
3  501  2021     4
4  550  2021     5
5  560  2021     6
```

Comment: thanks your solution worked as expected.

Comment: I updated question can you please try to update your solution I added 1 more year 2020 and need to reassign rank.

Comment: @Python_help - So need concat first by `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)` and then add column `df['Rank'] = np.arange(len(df)) + 1` ?